# how to edit a already deployed pipeline in data fusion?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion

I am trying to edit a pipeline which is already deployed I understand that we can duplicate a same pipeline and rename it but how can do make a change in existing pipeline as renaming would require a change in production scheduling jobs as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, There is not such edit option to do so.

Answer (score 0):

### There is one way thru http calls executor..

1. Open https://<cdf instnace url  ..datafusion.googleusercontent.com>/cdap/httpexecutor
2. Select PUT(to change pipeline code) from drop down and give
   namespaces/<namespaces_name>/apps/<pipeline_name>
3. Go to body part and paste the new pipeline code (export the code of updated pipeline to i.e. json formatted)
4. Click on SEND and Response would come as "Deploy Complete" with status code 200.